# Why can't I iterate over a ChannelLocal?

Tags: netty

I don't know the internals of ChannelLocal, but currently it seems not possible to iterate. I think of it as a collection of channel-object-mappings, so I think it should be possible. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way atm... But I like the idea we could just let it implement Iterable.

Could you open a issue for this at our bugtracker [1].

[1] https://github.com/netty/netty/issues

Comment: The feature was implemented from Norman Maurer for the upcoming release 3.5.0.Final

https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/307

Thank, you!

Comment: Just for the record.. We just released 3.4.3.Final and included the feature in it. See http://netty.io/blog/2012/05/05/